# Can this below dashboard be devloped with Standard Salesforce functionality??

Tags: lightning-aura-components, reporting, dashboard, report-chart, chartjs

Can this below chart be developed with Standard salesforce features. 
1. Chart should allow negative values in Y-axis.
2. X-axis should allow more than 1 system for each unit as shown in image.
3. Legends should be displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can build this in a standard [Report](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rd_reports_overview.htm&type=5). Create a report that groups by System and by Year, and Sums Net Gain, then you can add a chart to this report, or place it in a [Dashboard](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rd_dashboards_overview.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I tried as per your inputs It worked with 2 Systems.  I have 3 systems along with year field. But salesforce grouping allowing only 3 levels of grouping, but I need 4 levels(3 systems+ Year). Is there any workaround??

Comment: @Alex That sounds like a data structure issue. You shouldn't need more than two fields to get this chart if your data is right.

Comment: You are right @Sfdcfox. My mistake. I would be needing only 2 level grouping here. Thank you!